# Parse a string of pre-specified format in MATLAB

Tags: regex, string, matlab, split

I would like to parse a string in MATLAB that has a prespecified format. For instance, I would like to parse the following string,

`s = 'a(1,2)+b_c15_d.ext'`

so that I can get the substring before '(', i.e., the substring 'a', the numbers that are between the parentheses, i.e, 1 and 2, and so on (the substring 'b' between the '+' and '_', and the substring 'd' before the extension).

I can do it using `regexp` and `split`, but is there a more convenient way of doing this?

Comment: Initially this seems really obvious: `s(1:regexp(s, '(')-1)` and similar variants for each type. But what you're actually asking is for someone to code some custom string parser, based on a vague set of rules, which looks like you're trying to build your own compiler or something? Are you sure you're not just looking for `eval(s)`?

Comment: @Wolfie thanks for your response. No, I'm not looking for `eval`; I don't build a compiler either :) I just need to parse the result files of some experiments and I need to do it automatcally. So if an arbitrary file is of the form `s = 'a(1,2)+b_c15_d.ext'`, then I would expect that I could get what I want by giving the general format of the string, something like `frmt = '%s(%d,%d)+%s_c%s_%s.ext', but I don't know how...

Comment: You were on the right track with your format string, and I feel like you may have been misled by the accepted answer.  There are convenient alternatives to `regexp` and `split` that work here with your format.

Comment: @informaton thank you very much, your answer helped a lot! I have to accept your answer since is more explanatory and closer to what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could do it using regexp and 'split', but I hope there is a more convenient way of doing so.

`textscan` offers a simple, perhaps convenient, alternative to `regexp` and `split`.

```
 a = textscan(s,'%c(%d,%d)+%c_%c%d_%c.ext');
```

The results are in order as:

```
 >> a = 

     'a'    [1]    [2]    'b'    'c'    [15]    'd'
```

If you are going to have more than one character for your substring, `%c` to a modified `%[]` (character string) depending on your needs.  For example:

```
a = textscan(s,'%[^(](%d,%d)+%[^_]_%[^_]_%[^.].ext')
```

The `%[^(]` above will collect characters from the string until the string ends or a `'('` is reached on the string and place the result in the first cell of the output.  The `'('` is still on the string/stream however, so we remove it directly, by reading it, as shown.

`sscanf` is another option, but manipulating the output format is more involved.

Answer (score 2):

Using `regexp` and `split` really isn't that inconvenient, you can do it nicely in 2 lines

```
r = regexp(s,'[()\+_(_c)(.ext)]', 'split');
r = r(~cellfun(@isempty, r))

>> r = {'a' '1,2' 'b' '15' 'd'}
```

I'm not sure if this is similar to what you'd already tried, since you didn't post any code.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.